# Are Saint Jimmy and the Jesus of Suburbia two different representations of the same person?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

Green day's *American Idiot* album tells a very interesting story driven by three different characters Saint Jimmy, the Jesus of Suburbia, and Whatshername. I've always heard that Saint Jimmy and the Jesus of Suburbia are two different representations of the same person. Is this true?

Answer (score 4):

I've always believed that Jesus of Suburbia was a kid/man who was growing restless of being a nobody in a nowhere town, so he heads off into the city to find this exciting life he's always wanted.  He's walking along Hollywood Boulevard (the boulevard of broken dreams) and somehow gets into the whole underground scene, where he becomes reborn as St. Jimmy; an outspoken member of a rebellious movement.

Comment: some [additional info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Idiot#Story), which confirms your story.